# Need to get the current page URL while using ajax method in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to get the current page URL.

Actually, I have used pop up box while click the link in current page in Codeigniter framework
Here, I have displayed the some content in pop up box using ajax response method.
In that content, I have coded as

> $this->uri->segment(2)

.
Here I got only url which is given in ajax method, but I need to get the URL of the page which I have hold the pop up box.

Answer (score 1):

**In Codeigniter:**

For getting complete URL:

By using the `current_url()` method you can get the current page URl of the page.

Example:

```
$page_url=current_url();
echo $page_url;
```

For getting URI segments:

By using the following statement you can get the segments in the URI.

Syntax:

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
       where n=1 for controller
                 n=2 for method
                 n=3,4,5,6........ for parameters.
```

Example:

```
URL:   **http://example.com/project_name/login/home**

echo $this->uri->segment(1); //It will returns login as output
echo $this->uri->segment(2); //It will returns home as output
```

For getting current controller and method names:

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); //It will returns controller name
$this->router->fetch_method(); //It will return current method name.
```

**In jQuery:**
You can use jQuery to get current page url like:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: This is in jQuery, but I need to get this in php

Comment: Hi, Is there any chance to get the current URL in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, you can use URI class to get current uri segment.

```
$currentUrl = base_url().$this->uri->uri_string();
```

In this case, you need to set base_url in config file and load url helper to use `base_url()` function.

Comment: just short way base_url(uri_string());

Answer (score 0):

Get current page URL:
eg:

```
www.domain.com/index.php/controller/function

        $this->load->helper("url");
        $current_uri = uri_string(); 

echo $current_uri; // this would echo '/controller/function'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look at the referrer to get the url of the popup (rather than the destination AJAX url). This can be done using the UserAgent class (`$this->agent->referrer()`)

See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html